# How to call a function after the update progress is completed in an update panel?

Tags: panel, progress

I have a button in the update panel. Another function say function1 is executed in the click event of this button. I want to call a javascript function once the function1 completes execution. How will I know when the function1 has completed its execution?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming function1 runs onthe server, and function2 on the client,
handle the endRequest event of the Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager MSAjax class.